# Can PDFsharp help me detect overlapping text?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pdf, pdfsharp

**Question**: Given a PDF file, can I (easily) check for overlapping text using PDFsharp (or another .NET compatible PDF library)?

A solution that checks for overlapping letters (of two different text blocks) is preferred, but a solution that solely checks for overlapping bounding boxes is acceptable as well.

**What I already tried**: An obvious solution would be to extract all text components with their bounding boxes and check those for overlap. However, I did not find a way in PDFsharp to extract text components with their bounding boxes. To [avoid the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'm asking for the general problem rather than for how to extract text with PDFsharp.

---

**Background**: I am writing unit tests for our reporting component. Reports are generated as PDF files, using both the PDF rendering component of RDLC reports as well as direct PDF output with PdfSharp.

In my unit tests, I want to test these reports using different data sets and languages and find out *whether there is overlapping text*. At the moment, the unit tests just export PDFs for every combination I want to test and someone has to manually look through them. I'd like to automate that.

Answer (score 2):

The code below shows how to implement this detection using [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library (since you asked about solutions including other libraries):

```
public void TestCharacterOverlap()
{
    PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument("sample.pdf");

    for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        List<PdfVisualRectangle[]> overlaps = GetPageOverlaps(document.Pages[i]);
        if (overlaps.Count > 0)
        {
            // We have character overlapping.
        }
    }
}

public List<PdfVisualRectangle[]> GetPageOverlaps(PdfPage page)
{
    List<PdfVisualRectangle[]> overlaps = new List<PdfVisualRectangle[]>();

    PdfContentExtractor ce = new PdfContentExtractor(page);
    PdfTextFragmentCollection tfc = ce.ExtractTextFragments();

    for (int i = 0; i < tfc.Count; i++)
    {
        PdfTextGlyphCollection currentGlyphs = tfc[i].Glyphs;

        for (int j = 0; j < currentGlyphs.Count; j++)
        {
            // Start comparing current glyph to remaining extracted glyphs.
            for (int k = i; k < tfc.Count; k++)
            {
                PdfTextGlyphCollection nextGlyphs = tfc[k].Glyphs;
                // l = j + 1 - we avoid comparing current glyph with itself
                for (int l = j + 1; l < nextGlyphs.Count; l++)
                {
                    PdfVisualRectangle crtGlyphRect = GetGlyphRectangle(currentGlyphs[j].GlyphCorners);
                    PdfVisualRectangle nextGlyphRect = GetGlyphRectangle(nextGlyphs[l].GlyphCorners);
                    if (Intersect(crtGlyphRect, nextGlyphRect))
                    {
                        PdfVisualRectangle[] overlap = new PdfVisualRectangle[] { crtGlyphRect, nextGlyphRect };
                        overlaps.Add(overlap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return overlaps;
}

public PdfVisualRectangle GetGlyphRectangle(PdfPoint[] glyphCorners)
{
    double minX = Math.Min(Math.Min(glyphCorners[0].X, glyphCorners[1].X), Math.Min(glyphCorners[2].X, glyphCorners[3].X));
    double minY = Math.Min(Math.Min(glyphCorners[0].Y, glyphCorners[1].Y), Math.Min(glyphCorners[2].Y, glyphCorners[3].Y));
    double maxX = Math.Max(Math.Max(glyphCorners[0].X, glyphCorners[1].X), Math.Max(glyphCorners[2].X, glyphCorners[3].X));
    double maxY = Math.Max(Math.Max(glyphCorners[0].Y, glyphCorners[1].Y), Math.Max(glyphCorners[2].Y, glyphCorners[3].Y));

    return new PdfVisualRectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
}

public bool Intersect(PdfVisualRectangle rc1, PdfVisualRectangle rc2)
{
    bool intersect = (rc1.Left < rc2.Left + rc2.Width) && (rc1.Left + rc1.Width > rc2.Left) &&
        (rc1.Top < rc2.Top + rc2.Height) && (rc1.Top + rc1.Height > rc2.Top);

    return intersect;
}
```

A few notes about the code:
- in most situations (regular horizontal text) the glyph corners (4 points) form a rectangle. But for diagonal text or skewed characters the glyph corners are a quadrilateral shape so you have to implement a more complex intersection procedure
- overlap testing can be further polished for allowing a small degree of overlapping, let's say 2 characters overlap if the intersection is larger than X% of character area. This is why the GetPageOverlaps method returns a collection of paired rectangles so they can be further processed if needed.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library.

Comment: Note that you will probably have to develop a strategy to deal with [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) to avoid false positives.